# Regex: match string between mandatory and optional groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse file with list of movies where strings like:

```
id,title (year),genre1|genre2|genre3
```

Year field is optional, but there are movies with some parts of title in brackets

So I have such regex:

```
(?:^\s*(\d+)\s*,.*?)(?:.*?\((\d{4})\))?(?:.*,\s*(.*)$)
```

[my regex result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtqoq.png)

How can I improve it to catch title which is between id and optional year (or genres if there is no year)?

Data example:

```
1,Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls(1995),Comedy
20,Money Train (1995),Action|Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller
21,Get Shorty (1995),Comedy|Crime|Thriller
22,Copycat ,Crime|Drama|Horror|Mystery|Thriller
23,Assassins (1995),Action|Crime|Thriller
24,"Powder (1995)",Drama|Sci-Fi
25,Leaving (5) Las Vegas ,Drama|Romance
```

Comment: It looks like you should be using a CSV parser, not a regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The year is always before a comma, so don't put `.*` before the comma after the year.

```
^\s*(\d+)\s*,(.*?)(?:\((\d{4})\))?\s*,\s*(.*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rm8SbM/1)